# What is this move/attack by Gogeta called?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In *Dragon Ball Super: Broly*, we got a superb fight between Broly and Gogeta, which ends

> in a Perfect form Gogeta Blue, which does not take a single hit from the moment he transforms into Blue.

I searched the Internet and was unable to find a name for one of his final moves, where Gogeta charges at Broly and loads him with energy by punching him, before backflip-kicking him into the air. He then crosses his hands, arms straight, before pulling them up in the air and provoking somewhat of a nuclear blast. I cut the extract as a GIF because it's really cool:

[image: Gogeta move/attack described above]

As far as I searched, I didn't find any official name. Is there an official name for this move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked it up online, and it appears to be called `Meteor Explosion` in multiple video games of the franchise, per the [Dragon Ball Fandom wiki](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Meteor_Explosion), so I would think that is the official name of the move. I know that wikis aren't perfect, but some of these are video games run by Bandai Namco themselves.